# Construction of Gtk#-FileChooserDialog crashes application on Windows

Tags: c#, mono, gtk#, filechooser

I have programmed a small C# application using MonoDevelop on Ubuntu. I have used the Gtk#-library in order to render the graphical user interface controls. However, when I execute the application on Windows using mono, the application always hangs at the construction of the FileChooserDialog which means that the user interface thread does not respond anymore.

```
FileChooserDialog OpenFileDialog = new FileChooserDialog ("Open file...", this, FileChooserAction.Open);
```

This line of code is placed in an OnMenuItemActivatedEvent and works fine on Ubuntu. Can anyone suggest why it does not work on Windows?

Comment: Is your `Main` method marked with `[STAThread]`?

Comment: It was not yet. But I experience the same behaviour when I add it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it is not a real satisfying solution to me, I have now setup Visual Studio for Mono projects as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11346898/778421) answer. Nevertheless, after the compilation on Windows, I can execute the application on both operating systems, Windows and Ubuntu which is what I mainly want.